# Run getElementById bound to success of AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm building a small quiz. The score is stored in a variable `quizScore` - each question on the quiz is output using AJAX. The single AJAX call grabs the ID of the button pressed (so, on question 2, the button ID is 2a which takes you to the next AJAX refresh of question2a.php)

On the last AJAX call, which calls up a file called questionendQuiz.php, I want to have the output of the variable `quizScore`. I need to bind this output to an event, so success of loading that through AJAX makes sense.

```
/* Output score */
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("quizWrapper").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    if (buttonID == "question_endQuiz") {
        document.getElementById("scoreOut").innerHTML = quizScore;
    }
}
```

So this should output `quizScore` into `div id="scoreOut"` when the successful AJAX content loads.

I've double checked the score is actually working by using console logs. It is building the score correctly (see here it outputs the score in the console http://francesca-designed.me/quiz/quiz.php

I can't work out what is wrong with the success if statement to cause it to not output the score?

AJAX request, I've omitted some things that aren't useful to this question like the correct answer scoring and the start of the quiz:

```
/* Quiz Score */
var quizScore = 0; /* Takes you to each next question, based on ButtonID */

function nextQuestion(buttonID) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("quizWrapper").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var splitID = buttonID.split('_');
    var questionID = splitID.pop();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "question" + questionID + ".php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(); /* Output score */
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("quizWrapper").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (buttonID == "question_endQuiz") {
            document.getElementById("scoreOut").innerHTML = quizScore;
        }
    }
}
```

The button that marks the end of the quiz is:

```
<button id="question_endQuiz" onClick="nextQuestion(this.id)">See your score</button>
```

Comment: Could we see the ajax request?

Comment: @mosho added. it's pretty long so I've removed: correct answer scoring, quiz start.

Comment: you `.send()` the request and then immediately check the readyState, so it's not going to be true at that point in time because you just sent the request and browser needs to go through process of sending request and receive response. That's why there's a `onreadystatechange` callback : so that you can hook code to when the response actually happens. And you're actually using already further above. That's where it should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score recording part should go into `onreadystatechange` as well. It is the callback for the request, and gets executed after the response is received, rather than before as in the code you provided.

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("quizWrapper").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if (buttonID == "question_endQuiz") {
                document.getElementById("scoreOut").innerHTML = quizScore;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I've added this in. I'm now getting an error at the beginning because it cannot find `question_endQuiz` (which is true, it does not appear until the last page is clicked). And it does not show a result. See link in post to see the error yourself.

Comment: My bad, seems to be working now. Must've been a caching issue. Thanks!